# SharpDevelop Changing code style

Tags: c#, coding-style, sharpdevelop

I would want to change the style of SharpDevelop from this

---

[image: Before]

---

to this

---

[image: required]

---

Comment: this is not an answer nor a suggestion but i prefer the first one. `:D`

Comment: Read [faq] and [ask] one more time..

Comment: [AStyle AddIn for SharpDevelop](http://alex.codeplex.com/) maybe works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify SharpDevelop source file so as to get your custom style right now. There is no IDE setting to change it.

As a workaround, you might use AStyle Addin,

http://alex.codeplex.com/